# I've an electron project and I'd like to use vueJS with it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, electron, vue-component, electron-builder

I've an electron project and I'd like to use vueJS with it...I need someone to explain what should I do in ordered steps

Comment: you should read https://electronjs.org/docs and https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: @JeffProd Can I use electron-vue and move the files in my electron project to the project itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather vague for this site. If you want Vue.js to be the main framework for your electron app, [this package](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) is a good option. It is really well done, and very well documented [here](https://simulatedgreg.gitbooks.io/electron-vue/content/en/).

If, however, you just want to use Vue for a small part of your app, you can simply import it via npm (`npm install vue -s`) and use it where needed.

```
import Vue from 'vue'

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#element',
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  ...
})
```

In this case, you'll find the [Getting Started](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started) section of the vue docs helpful. Good Luck!

Comment: I've created Vue Project with Vue CLI 3 and I've installed electron-builder plugin. I'll move the files from electron project to the vue project Is that a good solution?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanFawzy, I would recommend the other way around. Move your Vue files into your Electron project. If your end goal is an electron app, your project needs to be an electron project – not a Vue CLI project.